# why there is errorneous output on start up and how to avoid it?

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

I wrote an Arduino code to get the latitude,longitude,speed,date and time using the GPS SKG 13BL at every 5 secs and sent it to the database with the help of a php code using GSM 900A.The code is as follows :

```
#include <NeoSWSerial.h>

#include <AltSoftSerial.h>
#include <NMEAGPS.h>

NeoSWSerial GSM(2, 3); // RX, TX: Connect TXD to RX & RXD to TX

static const int RXPin = 8, TXPin = 9;
AltSoftSerial gpsPort(RXPin, TXPin);
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

NMEAGPS gps;
gps_fix fix;
uint8_t fixCount = 0;
char dt[15],tm[15],lati[10],longi[10];


enum _parseState {
  PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE,

  PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO,

  PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE,

  PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE,
  PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT,
  PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH,

  PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH,
  PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT
};

enum _actionState {
  AS_IDLE,
  AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE
};

byte actionState = AS_IDLE;
unsigned long lastActionTime = 0;

int s;

byte parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
char buffer[160],url[160];
byte pos = 0;

int contentLength = 0;

void resetBuffer() {
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  pos = 0;
}

void sendGSM(const char* msg, int waitMs = 500) {
  GSM.println(msg);
  while(GSM.available()) {
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }
  //delay(waitMs);
}

void setup()
{
  GSM.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gpsPort.begin(GPSBaud);

  Serial.println(F("Hinder LOADING....."));
  Serial.println(F("obtain gps and store data to database"));
  Serial.println(F("Testing by : "));
  Serial.println(F("Nikhil,Muthumani and Mathews"));
  Serial.println();

  sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"vodafone\"");  
  delay(500);
  sendGSM("AT+SAPBR=1,1",3000);
  delay(500);
  sendGSM("AT+HTTPINIT"); 
  delay(500); 
  sendGSM("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  delay(500);
}

void loop()
{ 
  unsigned long now = millis();
  while (gps.available( gpsPort )) {
    fix = gps.read();
     //Serial.println(F("b"));
    // Once every 5 seconds...    
    if (++fixCount >= 5) {
       //Serial.println(F("a"));
      displayInfo();

      //send the next report if previous one is finished
      if ( actionState == AS_IDLE ) {
      sprintf(url, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://********.com/***er.php?lat=%s&lng=%s&speed=%d&date=%s&time=%s\"",lati,longi,s,dt,tm );
      sendGSM(url);
     // lastActionTime = now;
      parseState = PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE; // a new state
      actionState = AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE;
      fixCount = 0;
    }

    }
  }

/*  if ((gps.statistics.chars < 10) && (millis() > 5000)) {
     Serial.println( F("No GPS detected: check wiring.") );
     while(true);
     block=1;
    }*/

  while(GSM.available()) {
    //lastActionTime = now;
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }
 }


void displayInfo()
{
  Serial.print(F("Location: ")); 
  if (fix.valid.location) {
    dtostrf( fix.latitude(),7,5,lati);
    //sprintf(lati,"%d",fix.latitude(),5);
    Serial.print(lati);
    Serial.print( ',' );
    dtostrf( fix.longitude(),8,5,longi);
    //sprintf(longi,"%d",fix.longitude(),5);
    Serial.print(longi);
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Speed: ")); 
  if (fix.valid.speed) {
    s=fix.speed_kph();
    Serial.print(s);
    Serial.print(F(" KMPH "));
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  // Shift the date/time to local time
  NeoGPS::clock_t localSeconds;
  NeoGPS::time_t  localTime;
  if (fix.valid.date && fix.valid.time) {
    using namespace NeoGPS; // save a little typing below...

    localSeconds = (clock_t) fix.dateTime; // convert structure to a second count
    localSeconds += 5 * SECONDS_PER_HOUR + 30 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE; // shift timezone
    localTime = localSeconds;              // convert back to a structure
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Date : "));
  if (fix.valid.date) {
    sprintf(dt,"%02d/%02d/20%d",fix.dateTime.date,fix.dateTime.month,fix.dateTime.year);
    Serial.print(dt);
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Time : "));
  if (fix.valid.time) {
    if (localTime.hours>12)localTime.hours-=12;//To convert 24 hr format to 12 hr format
    sprintf(tm,"%02d:%02d:%02d",localTime.hours,localTime.minutes,localTime.seconds);
    Serial.print(tm);
    //block=1;
  } else {
    Serial.print(F("INVALID"));
  }

  Serial.println();
}

void parseATText(byte b) {

  buffer[pos++] = b;

  if ( pos >= sizeof(buffer) )
    resetBuffer(); // just to be safe

  /*
   // Detailed debugging
   Serial.println();
   Serial.print("state = ");
   Serial.println(state);
   Serial.print("b = ");
   Serial.println(b);
   Serial.print("pos = ");
   Serial.println(pos);
   Serial.print("buffer = ");
   Serial.println(buffer);*/

  switch (parseState) {

  case PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE:
    {
      parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
      sendGSM("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
     /*  while(GSM.available()) {
    //lastActionTime = now;
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }*/

    }
    break;

  case PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE: 
    {
      if ( b == '\n' )
        resetBuffer();
      else {        
        if ( pos == 3 && strcmp(buffer, "AT+") == 0 ) {
          parseState = PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO;
        }
        else if ( b == ':' ) {
          //Serial.print("Checking message type: ");
          //Serial.println(buffer);

          if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPACTION:") == 0 ) {
            Serial.println("Received HTTPACTION");
            parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE;
          }
          else if ( strcmp(buffer, "+HTTPREAD:") == 0 ) {
            Serial.println("Received HTTPREAD");            
            parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH;
          }
          resetBuffer();
        }
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_IGNORING_COMMAND_ECHO:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        Serial.print("Ignoring echo: ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_TYPE:
    {
      if ( b == ',' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION type is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_RESULT:
    {
      if ( b == ',' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION result is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);
        parseState = PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPACTION_LENGTH:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        Serial.print("HTTPACTION length is ");
        Serial.println(buffer);

        // now request content
        GSM.print("AT+HTTPREAD=0,");
        GSM.println(buffer);

        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPREAD_LENGTH:
    {
      if ( b == '\n' ) {
        contentLength = atoi(buffer);
        Serial.print("HTTPREAD length is ");
        Serial.println(contentLength);

        Serial.print("HTTPREAD content: ");

        parseState = PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT;
        resetBuffer();
      }
    }
    break;

  case PS_HTTPREAD_CONTENT:
    {
      // for this demo I'm just showing the content bytes in the serial monitor
      Serial.write(b);

      contentLength--;

      if ( contentLength <= 0 ) {

        // all content bytes have now been read

        parseState = PS_DETECT_MSG_TYPE;
        resetBuffer();

        Serial.print("\n\n\n");

        actionState = AS_IDLE;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

When I test the code it shows the output as : [image] as you can see after `Ignoring echo: AT+HTTPREAD=0,0`
the GPS output is printed out at every sec (not at 5 sec interval) and also does not perform rest of the actions (i.e Sending to database is not performed). And I press reset button  and the output is : [image]Even though it prints the GPS output at every sec it inserted the values into database.And once again I press reset button then it works fine.So why do this error occurs and is there a way to solve this.And can I make the program run only when GPS data is available (because now if GPS data is not available it shows some error nature ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:)

> Why does this error occur, and is there a way to solve this?

Because the GSM operations take time, the GPS data has time to accumulate.  Then the `while (gps.available` loop will execute multiple times without breaking.  It calls `displayInfo` every time because `fixCount >= 5`.  `fixCount` is 6, 7, 8, etc. in consecutive seconds.

To solve this problem, you need to be more restrictive about starting the sending process:

```
void loop()
{ 
  while (gps.available( gpsPort )) {
    fix = gps.read();
     //Serial.println(F("b"));

    //send a report once every 5 seconds if previous one is finished
    if ((++fixCount >= 5) && (actionState == AS_IDLE)) {

      //Serial.println(F("a"));
      displayInfo();

      sprintf(url, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://********.com/***er.php?lat=%s&lng=%s&speed=%d&date=%s&time=%s\"",lati,longi,s,dt,tm );
      sendGSM(url);
      parseState  = PS_HTTPPARA_RESPONSE; // a new state
      actionState = AS_WAITING_FOR_RESPONSE;
      fixCount    = 0;
    }
  }

  while(GSM.available()) {
    parseATText(GSM.read());
  }
}
```

The combined `if` test displays GPS info only when the GSM process begins.  Then it will continue to read fixes, keeping the queue emptied.  When the state goes back to AS_IDLE, it can send another update.  Notice how this loop structure will continue counting fixes while the GSM process is completing.  If the GSM process takes 5 seconds or more, it will immediately send another update when the previous GSM send has completed.

If you want it to wait an *additional* 5 seconds between each GSM update, don't increment the `fixCount` until the GSM process has completed (AS_IDLE).  Then the updates will be sent once every 5 + (GSM send time) seconds, perhaps once every 15 seconds.

> can I make the program run only when GPS data is available (because now if GPS data is not available it shows some error nature ).

Yes, make the `if` test even *more* restrictive by testing the valid flags:

```
    //send a report once every 5 seconds if the data is valid
    //   and the previous one is finished
    if ((fix.valid.location && fix.valid.date && fix.valid.time) &&
        (++fixCount >= 5) &&
        (actionState == AS_IDLE)) {
```

This only counts valid fixes; the `fixCount` will not increment unless those 3 pieces are valid.

NOTE: You probably don't have to test `fix.valid.speed`, as it will be marked as invalid when you are stationary.  Testing the valid flags could be removed from `displayInfo()`:

```
void displayInfo()
{
  Serial.print(F("Location: ")); 
  dtostrf( fix.latitude(),7,5,lati);
  Serial.print(lati);
  Serial.print( ',' );
  dtostrf( fix.longitude(),8,5,longi);
  Serial.print(longi);

  Serial.print(F("  Speed: ")); 
  if (fix.valid.speed) {
    s=fix.speed_kph();
  } else {
    s=0;
  }
  Serial.print(s);
  Serial.print(F(" KMPH "));

  // Shift the date/time to local time
  NeoGPS::clock_t localSeconds;
  NeoGPS::time_t  localTime;
  {
    using namespace NeoGPS; // save a little typing below...

    localSeconds = (clock_t) fix.dateTime; // convert structure to a second count
    localSeconds += 5 * SECONDS_PER_HOUR + 30 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE; // shift timezone
    localTime = localSeconds;              // convert back to a structure
  }

  Serial.print(F("  Date : "));
  sprintf(dt,"%02d/%02d/20%d",fix.dateTime.date,fix.dateTime.month,fix.dateTime.year);
  Serial.print(dt);

  Serial.print(F("  Time : "));
  if (localTime.hours>12)localTime.hours-=12;//To convert 24 hr format to 12 hr format
  sprintf(tm,"%02d:%02d:%02d",localTime.hours,localTime.minutes,localTime.seconds);
  Serial.print(tm);
  //block=1;

  Serial.println();
}
```

`displayInfo` still checks `fix.valid.speed` and uses `0` when there is no speed (i.e., when you're stationary).